# is there a way to set an alternative viewer for `get-help`?

Tags: powershell

As I explore powershell, I use get-help a lot. But, the viewer is just 'more', this means no searching, going back, etc. Is there a way to set an alternative viewer for the console? (that is, I'm not looking for something that GUI/browser based)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell uses the pre-defined function `more()` for paging (which calls the pager `more.com` that ships with Windows):

```
PS C:\> (Get-Item function:more).Definition
param([string[]]$paths)

$OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::OutputEncoding

if($paths)
{
    foreach ($file in $paths)
    {
        Get-Content $file | more.com
    }
}
else
{
    $input | more.com
}
```

You can override it by defining an alias to a program or function of your own choice (since aliases take precedence over functions). For instance:

```
Set-Alias more 'C:\path\to\less.exe'
```

Or you could replace the function with an implementation of your own:

```
Remove-Item function:more

function more {
  # your implementation here
}
```

Either way you'd persist the change by putting it into your [profile](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/).